# Uncaught ReferenceError: monaco is not defined

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I am trying to run [Monaco Editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) but it gives an error. `Uncaught ReferenceError: monaco is not defined`.

I'm running a local web server and I can see the loader.js is being loaded in the Firefox Developer Tools. Also when I type monaco into the Firefox's console it says that it is not defined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="height: 100%"></div>

<script>
    monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
        value: "function hello() {\n\talert('Hello world!');\n}",
        language: 'javascript'
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A website is not an Electron app with a node back-end.

Comment: @Andreas how they run this [demo](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html)? When I type "ale" it suggests "alert" and other functions without making any request to the back-end. That is what I want to accomplish; auto-suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the link to the editor style sheet.  Something like this

```
<link
            rel="stylesheet"
            data-name="vs/editor/editor.main"
            href="../node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.css"
        />
```

See the example [browser-script-editor](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/samples/browser-script-editor/index.html).